# Import radio stations in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins

I know Rhythmbox stores all kind of information in `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`.

All entries with `type="iradio"` are radio stations.

I would like to import radio stations from [TuneIn](http://tunein.com/).

My question is: is there any API I can use to manipulate this xml database?

I mean, I can do it by hand, but since Rhythmbox already manipulates it, and it has plugin support, I guess there is some better way to update it then doing it outside of the app.

**UPDATE**

I ended up updating it by hand https://github.com/umpirsky/rhytmbox-tunein-import.

Comment: can you explain how TuneIn exports radiostations - please give an example of the format for the file containing the radiostation details.

Comment: @fossfreedom Never mind, I will extract that info from TuneIn xml, I am just asking if there is any API to manipulate `rhythmdb.xml`. Thanks.

Comment: well yes - you can write a python plugin to write stuff into the RB database.  I can give you a better answer though if you can supply an example XML.

Comment: @fossfreedom What XML? Imagine there is no XML, just some python objects you need to write to `rhythmdb.xml`. If you need  `rhythmdb.xml` example https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/a5a0b634dd5d7b408a16.

Comment: @fossfreedom https://github.com/umpirsky/rhytmbox-tunein-import/blob/master/import.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rhythmbox does have a [C](https://developer.gnome.org/rhythmbox/unstable/index.html) / [Python](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#RB-3.0) API which you can use to add and change details of tracks / songs/ radio stations / podcasts etc.

You don't write directly to the local rhythmdb.xml - this is an internal XML format subject to change between versions.

In the following sample the key parts are as follows:

- "iradio" is the entry_type that corresponds to internet radio stations stored in the internal database
- you create new entries via `RB.RhythmDBEntry.new`
- you must commit the entry to the database before modifying additional details such as the radio station title and the station genre

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Peas
from gi.repository import RB

class SamplePython(GObject.Object, Peas.Activatable):
    __gtype_name = 'SamplePythonPlugin'
    object = GObject.property(type=GObject.GObject)

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.Object.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        print("activating sample python plugin")

        shell = self.object
        db = shell.props.db

        entry_type = db.entry_type_get_by_name("iradio")

        url = "http://bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx"
        entry = RB.RhythmDBEntry.new(db, entry_type, url)
        db.commit()
        db.entry_set(entry, RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE, url)
        db.entry_set(entry, RB.RhythmDBPropType.GENRE, "Unknown")

    def do_deactivate(self):
        print("deactivating sample python plugin")
```

Comment: Great, thanks. But this must be installed as Rhythmbox plugin, right? Since this is a one time thing, I would like to be able to run it manually, only once. What is appropriate approach there? And why this API is not documented, or it is?

Comment: correct - yes as a plugin.  Sorry, you will not be able to access the internal database outside of RB.  It is documented - see the links at the top of the answer - one for C and the other for python.

Comment: Thanks! Well, google does not find this page, that's sad. Probably SEO issues.

Comment: @fossfreedom I suppose it is possible to create a package for popular radio stations for particular country using python api. The package name could be `rhythmbox-radio-stations-uk`. Any idea where to store the plugin?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins

Comment: @fossfreedom Plugin doesn't appear in rhythmox 3.4.1 with above code when I moved it to `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins`. And I found nothing in the debug log. What am I missing?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam - the code is a snippet - you'll need to flesh it out into a proper plugin - with a .plugin file etc.

Comment: Yes. I know. The problem was that my radio station title was in unicode. Converring it to English fixed the problem. Thanks.